# Cannot find symbol java and JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have tried the solutions on stack overflow, but it didn't solve my problem so I would like to ask it

```
import java.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class mysql1
{
    static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    static final String usr = "root";
    static final String passwd = "";
    public static void main(String [] ar)
{
        Connection con = null;
//      boolean flag = True;
        int ch;
        String y;
        try
        {
            System.out.println("connecting to db...\n");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,usr,passwd);
            System.out.println("Database Connected.\n");
            CallableStatement cs = null;
            Statement stmnt = con.createStatement();
            do
            {
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("1.Create Table\n");
                System.out.println("2.Insert Table\n");
                System.out.println("3.Display Table\n");
                System.out.println("4.Update Table\n");
                System.out.println("5.Delete Table\n");
                System.out.println("6.Creating index\n");
                System.out.println("7.Show index\n");
                System.out.println("8.Create View\n");
                System.out.println("9.Show view\n");
                System.out.println("10. Inner Join\n");
                System.out.println("11. Right outer join\n");
                System.out.println("12. Left outer join\n");
                System.out.println("13. Cross join\n");
                System.out.println("14. Exit\n");
                System.out.println("Enter your choice");
                ch = in.nextInt();
                switch(ch)
                {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Creating table 1.\n");
                    String t1 = "create table employe(id int(10),"+"fname varchar(20),"+"lname varchar(15))";
                    stmnt.executeUpdate(t1);
                    System.out.println("Table 1 Created..\n");
                    System.out.println("Creating table 2.\n");
                    String t2 = "create table salary(id int(10),"+"fname varchar(20),"+"salray int(10))";
                    stmnt.executeUpdate(t2);
                    System.out.println("Table 2 Created..\n");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Entering data in 1st table\n");
                    do
                    {
                    System.out.println("Enter id:\n");
                    int id = in.nextInt();
                    String str = in.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter respective fname:\n");
                    String f = in.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter lname:\n");
                    String l = in.nextLine();
                    PreparedStatement pstmnt = con.preparedStatement("insert into employe values(?,?,?)");
                    pstmnt = setInt(1,id);
                    pstmnt = setString(2,f);
                    pstmnt = setString(3,f);
                    pstmnt.executeUpdate();
                    System.out.println("Do you want to continue? y/n");
                    String ans = in.nextLine();
                    }while(ans=='y');
                    System.out.println("Entering data in 2nd table\n");
                    do
                    {
                    System.out.println("Enter id:\n");
                    int id1 = in.nextInt();
                    String str1 = in.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter respective fname:\n");
                    String f1 = in.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter the salary\n");
                    int sal = in.nextInt();
                    PreparedStatement pstmnt = con.preparedStatement("insert into salary values(?,?,?)");
                    pstmnt = setInt(1,id);
                    pstmnt = setString(2,f);
                    pstmnt = setInt(3,f);
                    pstmnt.executeUpdate();
                    System.out.println("Do you want to continue? y/n");
                    String ans = in.nextLine();
                    }while(ans=='y');
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Displaying Table 1.....\n");
                    String display = "select * from employe";
                    ResultSet rs1 = stmnt.executeQuery(display);
                    System.out.println("ID \t FNAME \t LNAME");
                    while(rs1.next())
                    {
                        System.out.println(rs1.getInt(1)+"\t"+rs1.getString(2)+"\t"+rs1.getString(3));
                    }
                    System.out.println("Displaying Table 2.....\n");
                    String display1 = "select * from salary";
                    ResultSet rs4 = stmnt.executeQuery(display);
                    System.out.println("ID \t FNAME \t SALARY");
                    while(rs4.next())
                    {
                        System.out.println(rs4.getInt(1)+"\t"+rs4.getString(2)+"\t"+rs4.getInt(3));
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    String updat = "update employe set fname=?, lname=? where id=?";
                    System.out.println("Enter the id of the employe that you want to update:\n");
                    int id1 = in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter new fname:\n");
                    String f1 = in.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter new lname:\n");
                    String l1 = in.nextLine();
                    PreparedStatement ps = con.preparedStatement(updat);
                    ps.setString(1,f1);
                    ps.setString(2,l1);
                    ps.setInt(3,id1);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Delete enteries from table using id......\n");
                    String del = "delete from employe where id=?";
                    System.out.println("Enter the ID:\n");
                    int id2 = in.nextInt();
                    PreparedStatement ps1 = con.PreparedStatement(del);
                    ps1.setInt(1,id2);
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.println("Creating Index.....\n");
                    String ind = "create index inde on employe(fname)";
                    stmnt.executeUpdate(ind);
                    System.out.println("Index created .....n");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    System.out.println("Display index.....\n");
                    String inde = "show index from employe";
                    ResultSet rs2 = stmnt.executeQuery(inde);
                    System.out.println(rs2.getString(1)+"\t"+rs2.getString(2)+"\t"+rs2.getString(3)+"\t"+rs2.getString(4)+"\t"+rs2.getString(5)+"\t"+rs2.getString(6)+"\t"+rs2.getString(7)+"\t"+rs2.getString(8)+"\t"+rs2.getString(9)+"\t"+rs2.getString(10)+"\t"+rs2.getString(11)+"\t"+rs2.getString(12)+"\t\n");
                    break;
                case 8:
                    System.out.println("Create view......\n");
                    String vew = "create view v1 as select id,lname from employe";
                    stmnt.executeUpdate(vew);
                    System.out.println("View created\n");
                    break;
                case 9:
                    System.out.println("Displaying View......\n");
                    String disv = "select * from v1";
                    ResultSet rs3 = stmnt.executeQuery(disv);
                    while(rs3.next())
                    {
                        System.out.println(rs3.getInt(1)+"\t"+rs3.getString(2));
                    }
                    break;
                case 10:
                    String inner = "select * from employe e inner join salary sa on e.id=sa.id";
                    ResultSet rs5 = stmnt.executeQuery(inner);
                    System.out.println("ID\tFNME\tlname\n");
                    while(rs5.next())
                    {
                        System.out.println(rs5.getInt(1)+"\t"+rs5.getString(2)+"\t"+rs5.getString(3)+"\n");
                    }
                    inner1 = "select * from salary sal employe e on sal.id=e.id";
                    rs5 = stmnt.executeQuery(inner1);
                    System.out.println("ID\tFNME\tSalary\n");
                    while(rs5.next())
                    {
                        System.out.println(rs5.getInt(1)+"\t"+rs5.getString(2)+"\t"+rs5.getInt(3)+"\n");
                    }
                    break;
                case 11:
                    String rj = "select * from employe e right outer join salary s on e.id=s.id";
                    ResultSet rs6= stmnt.executeQuery(rj);
                    System.out.println("ID\tFnAME\tLNAME \n");
                    while(rs6.next())
                    {
                        System.out.println(rs6.getInt(1)+"\t"+rs6.getString(2)+"\t"+rs6.getString(3)+"\n");
                    }
                    rj = "select * from employe e right outer join salary s on e.id=s.id";
                    rs6= stmnt.executeQuery(rj);
                    System.out.println("ID\tFnAME\tLNAME \n");
                    while(rs6.next())
                    {
                        System.out.println(rs6.getInt(1)+"\t"+rs6.getString(2)+"\t"+rs6.getString(3)+"\n");
                    }
                }
                    System.out.println("Do you want to continue y/n :\n");
                    y = in.nextLine();
                }while(y=="y");
            }
            catch(SQLException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Cannot Connect to the db\n");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                System.out.println("Closing connection.......\n");
                if(con!=null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        con.close();
                    }
                    catch(SQLException ig)
                    {}
                }
            }
}
}
```

the above code is still missing some cases
Here are the errors

```
mysql1.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
                    PreparedStatement pstmnt = con.preparedStatement("insert into employe values(?,?,?)");
                                                  ^
  symbol:   method preparedStatement(String)
  location: variable con of type Connection
mysql1.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
                    pstmnt = setInt(1,id);
                             ^
  symbol:   method setInt(int,int)
  location: class mysql1
mysql1.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
                    pstmnt = setString(2,f);
                             ^
  symbol:   method setString(int,String)
  location: class mysql1
mysql1.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
                    pstmnt = setString(3,f);
                             ^
  symbol:   method setString(int,String)
  location: class mysql1
mysql1.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
                    }while(ans=='y');
                           ^
  symbol:   variable ans
  location: class mysql1
mysql1.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
                    PreparedStatement pstmnt = con.preparedStatement("insert into salary values(?,?,?)");
                                                  ^
  symbol:   method preparedStatement(String)
  location: variable con of type Connection
mysql1.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
                    pstmnt = setInt(1,id);
                                      ^
  symbol:   variable id
  location: class mysql1
mysql1.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
                    pstmnt = setString(2,f);
                                         ^
  symbol:   variable f
  location: class mysql1
mysql1.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
                    pstmnt = setInt(3,f);
                                      ^
  symbol:   variable f
  location: class mysql1
mysql1.java:91: error: cannot find symbol
                    }while(ans=='y');
                           ^
  symbol:   variable ans
  location: class mysql1
mysql1.java:119: error: cannot find symbol
                    PreparedStatement ps = con.preparedStatement(updat);
                                              ^
  symbol:   method preparedStatement(String)
  location: variable con of type Connection
mysql1.java:130: error: cannot find symbol
                    PreparedStatement ps1 = con.PreparedStatement(del);
                                               ^
  symbol:   method PreparedStatement(String)
  location: variable con of type Connection
mysql1.java:169: error: cannot find symbol
                    inner1 = "select * from salary sal employe e on sal.id=e.id";
                    ^
  symbol:   variable inner1
  location: class mysql1
mysql1.java:170: error: cannot find symbol
                    rs5 = stmnt.executeQuery(inner1);
                                             ^
  symbol:   variable inner1
  location: class mysql1
14 errors
```

I am using linux terminal to compile. I tried changing the class and method name to upper/lower cases. I also changed the class name and copied the entire program to different file and then compiled. I also checked the code in "Eclipse IDE" so I didn't find any typos too. Also I would like to know that whether the connectors will be called automatically if no then what should I add further?

I am beginner and this is my first JDBC code so, please help.

Comment: Open your code in Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA and hover on each error to get suggestions to fix the issues. There are too many method names and variable names typos in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with your code, some of which could have been avoided by 1) carefully scrutinizing your code and 2) using an IDE.

Some of the problems:

1. You have typos, for example `con.preparedStatement` instead of `con.prepareStatement`,
2. you need to call the `setXXX` methods **on an object**, for example on `pstmnt`,
3. you need to learn about block scope in Java, for example a variable `ans` declared in the block of a while loop can't be used outside of that block,
4. you try to use variable names that haven't been declared, for example `inner1`.

Comment: thanks i am new to java and jdbc concepts will work through